# Using Shockwave Flash object in Win Form, But it is asking for Adobe Flash player Installation

Tags: .net, winforms, flash

I have used the Shockwave Flash object com component in my .net Windows form. The problem is in one of the user's system,it is asking for the installation of Adobe Flash player as it is not already installed. But it is installed in his system.

Kindly let me know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a version mismatch?  Maybe the SWF your using requires a newer version that that user has installed?

Comment: Hi Herms,

Thanks for the reply. But, the user has the latest version installed in his machine.